# How do you add a custom uniqueness validation to an ActiveRecord model in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, rails-activerecord

I was perusing the [Ruby on Rails Guides article on ActiveRecord validations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html) and I came across this neat excerpt about the `uniqueness` validation:

> There is also a :case_sensitive option that you can use to define whether the uniqueness constraint will be case sensitive or not. This option defaults to true.

This is a very useful feature to ensure that two users can't sign up with the same username or email, for example. However, I want to use a similar validation but with a different method of determining the strings' equality. I want to make sure that all of my entries are unique under `squeeze`.

As an example, say my `Post` model has a text property `content`. I want to make sure that if `foo bar` is already in the database, it will not accept `foo   bar` or `foo           bar`. Is there a better way of doing this than just adding a custom validation to iterate over `Post.all`, `squeeze`ing each entry, and comparing it to the `squeeze`d `content`? I can't imagine that scales well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you might try to accomplish everything in “Rails” way, in this particular case I would go another path. If for some reason you want to keep `“foo        bar”` content in the database, just introduce a new field `squeezed_content`, implement a `post_commit` hook to update this field with a squeezed value of `content` and imply a validation on that newly introduced `squeezed_content` field enforcing it to be unique.

Also you might just store already squeezed values.

Answer (score 3):

You can add another column to your `posts` table called `squeezed_content` or something like that, then do something like this to use a built in uniqueness validation:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :set_squeezed_content
  validates :squeezed_content, uniqueness: true

  def set_squeezed_content
    self.squeezed_content = content.squeeze
  end
end
```